# React Native AirBnB Maps worldwide polygon

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, react-native

I'm trying to render a polygon on top of airbnb's react native map, on iOS using google maps. I'd like it to cover the entire map, but it seems like there is an issue when the polygon crosses the 0 longitude line.

This polygon doesn't show up at all

```
[
{ // South west
  latitude: -85,
  longitude: -180,
}, { // North west
  latitude: 85,
  longitude: -180,
}, { // north east
  latitude: 85,
  longitude: 180,
}, { // south east
  latitude: -85,
  longitude: 180,
},
]
```

But these 2 do, individually:

Right Hemishpere

```
[
{ // South west
  latitude: -85,
  longitude: 0,
}, { // North west
  latitude: 85,
  longitude: 0,
}, { // north east
  latitude: 85,
  longitude: 180,
}, { // south east
  latitude: -85,
  longitude: 180,
},
]
```

Left Hemisphere

```
[
{ // South west
  latitude: -85,
  longitude: -180,
}, { // North west
  latitude: 85,
  longitude: -180,
}, { // north east
  latitude: 85,
  longitude: 0,
}, { // south east
  latitude: -85,
  longitude: 0,
},
]
```

Is there a trick to cover the entire map with a single polygon?

Comment: Can you share some screenshot with more explaination?